# Get access to computed after calling function?

Tags: vue.js

Here is copy-past examples that will work if you will save it in index.html file:

I need to get access to `myvalue` and `{{my_dates['2018-07-10']['april']}}`.

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <!-- I need to get access to myvalue from computed -->
  <p>{{ myvalue }}</p>
  <p>{{ mess }}</p>

  <!-- trying to print values from here -->
 <p>{{my_dates['2018-07-10']['april']}}</p>
 <p>{{my_dates['2018-07-10']['may']}}</p>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    my_dates: {},
    mess: 'hello world'
  },
    computed: {
        // 
      myvalue: function () {
        return Number(this.my_dates['2018-07-10']['april']) + Number(this.my_dates['2018-07-10']['may'])
      }
    },

    methods: 
    {
      getTableData: function()
      {
          // GET /someUrl
          this.$http.get('http://dlang.ru/test').then(response => {
            // get body data
            this.my_dates = response.body;

          }, response => {
            // error callback
          });
      }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getTableData()
    }

})

</script>
</html>
```

The problem that I cant display `myvalue` and getting `Cannot read property`

Comment: `my_dates` is an empty object and so trying to access `this.my_dates['2018-07-10']['april']` is going to cause that error

Comment: How to fill it with `this.$http.get()`

Comment: Looks like you probably have it right (although can't say for sure, since idk what `response.body` is). But the function for your `myvalue` computed property is going to get called before that happens. So, put `if (!this.my_dates['2018-07-10']) { return; }` or something in the your `myvalue` function so that it doesn't try to access the property of something that doesn't exist.

Comment: But what should I to do if I need some computation? I need to sum display in HTML sum of `this.my_dates['2018-07-10']['april']` and `this.my_dates['2018-07-10']['may']`

Comment: Once `my_dates` is populated, then the computed property will update automatically